# How to load a js file with Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I want to get over a nasty problem that shows up yesterday during a demo to a client. We're using `jQuery`, loading it from google api. But yesterday, our ISP begin to cause some problems, and didn't load `jq.js` properly.

So, what I really want is to load a local file from the server if google api has an extrange behaviour (not that it's going to happen often, but at least doing local demos we won't get harmed again).

I know that `<script type="txt/javascript" src="googleapi"> somejs </script>` executes some js when file in src doesn't load, but don't know any way to get the file load there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside you can put the following lines:

```
var localScript = document.createElement("script");
localScript.type = "text/javascript";
localScript.src = "localJQ.js";
document.body.appendChild(localScript);
```

Comment: But as sadesh247 has pointed out if there are others scripts that depend on it, they won't work as expected. I'll mark this as the answer while looking how to fix it the way I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit :
I was a bit jumpy. The solution given by peirix is correct. I'll just use his code, to not let the wrong solution pollute this area. You can do

```
var localScript = document.createElement("script");
localScript.type = "text/javascript";
localScript.src = "localJQ.js";
document.body.appendChild(localScript);
```

to load Javascript dynamically.

Even this is prone to race conditions, however, if there are scripts in your page that depend on this script. Use with care.

This presentation - [Even Faster Websites](http://docs.google.com/Present?docid=ddfdgz6g_2056fq35k2fm) - elaborates on more techniques to load external files through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't directly answering your question, but JQuery's creator John Resig has an interesting [blog post](http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/) about executing the script tag contents when there is also a src attribute.